# safely restyling a page with jQuery has ugly load apperance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a website that I've styled and made functional with css just in case users are unable to use javascript. The thing is I make further style changes with jQuery and append an external stylesheet to the 'head'.

Now as the page loads, the style changes can be seen for a split second but it makes the page look very jittery (since some style changes are big). I do not want my users seeing this jittery load and would like some suggestions on what I can do to hide the page/provide a smooth transition if jQuery responds later (slow connection) during the style changes.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! : )

Comment: This may not be the answer you want, but this is one of the main reasons you should not use JS code as a crutch to style the UI; the delay in JS processing leads to a FOUC. If you can, move all the styling to CSS.

Comment: You can add a div that "covers" all the window while it's rendering. Then just hide this div and show the loaded page even the jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your feedback. After some thought and experimentation I had found something I prefer over javascript detection or a loading screen.

What I decided to do was to style the website expecting jQuery to work and then add a safety style sheet at the bottom that would normalize and create stable styles when jQuery and/or javascript is unavailable.

After all my script tags(bottom of body) I had placed this code beneath it.

```
<span id="removeMe">
        <script>$('#removeMe').remove();</script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/safety.css">
        <script>alert('There is a problem with jQuery');</script>
</span>
```

- If jQuery is offline, safety sheet will show and javascript will alert the problem.
- If javascript is offline it will still keep safety sheet.

**Note:** Please note that if any style changes are made with just pure javascript that interfere with the safety css, you may want to add another span for that scenario.

Comment: Why are you worried about UX for non-javascript users and then give them a developers alert afterwards? The whole point of a noscript experience is to provide a user-friendly experience. Even a developer would be annoyed to have an alert as cryptic as that. Also, it's common courtesy to at least lend upvotes to people who take the time to answer your question assuming the answers are viable solutions.

Comment: you should also reconsider your approach to something that isn't going to throw a javascript error. You can use a typeof($) condition to detect if jquery is undefined before you attempt the .remove(). Older browsers will trigger warning prompts when there are javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your problem is to not add the CSS via javascript, but instead include it as you normally would as a CSS link. For that stylesheet that is only targeting devices with javascript enabled, simply prepend a body class that gets added by the javascript. Something like this:

**JavaScript Stylesheet**

```
body.js header { display: block; }
body.js footer { display: block; }
body.js .my_jsmenu { display: block; }
body.js .etc { display: block; }
```

**Markup**

```
<head>
    <!-- normal stylesheets -->
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- js stylesheet -->
    <link href="myjs_styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.body.className += ' js';
    </script>
```

You can also use the html tag for it as a lot of other engines such as modernizr do. If you are using less or sass for your css this process is greatly simplified, but if you aren't then it can be a little tedious.

Personally, I avoid these javascript disabled solutions. Anybody who has javascript disabled at this point has intentionally disabled and knows that they aren't going to get a proper experience. We used to have to do this in the 2000s, but I'd say somewhere around 2011 it wasn't even worth taking into consideration.

As for jQuery adjusting the styles, please make sure that your CSS covers the initial load. You can use your jQuery to adjust based on user interaction or device resizing/scrolling/viewstate, but your site is going to get dinged in SEO if it doesn't render properly until after javascript is done running. Checkout Google Page Speed Insights for a proper analysis of your UX and it's loading configuration for more details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach if you want to use a loading div is as follows:

**Normal CSS (No JS Detected)**

```
#loading { display: none; }
```

**Javascript CSS**

```
#loading {
    display: block; position: fixed; width: 100%;
    height:100%; top:0; left:0; background-color:#fff;
    z-index: 100; /* must be higher than all other z-indexes on your page */
}
```

**Markup**

```
    <!-- End of DOM -->
    <div id="loading">
        <p>Loading message or ajax loading gif here</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#loading').fadeOut();
                }, 2500); // Timeout will need to be adjusted based testing the page with various connection speeds for a balance that suits your target user. Chrome dev tools can help with this
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is a simplified approach. You can turn the functionality into a function that you can reuse if needed, but that's the gist of how you go about it. There is no easy or reliable way to detect a user's speed, so if you have to play with the site to see what works best at different connection speeds to get a timeout that is balanced. This is not a preferred approach IMO, but if you wanted to go with a loading screen, this should give you a good jumping off point.

If your target audience is loading slow enough that the UI shows before the loading screen doesn't show fast enough, you can move the loading div to the opening of your body; just keep in mind that with IE8 and older, the z-index value will not matter. Any elements that are position relative or absolute that come later in the DOM will render on top of it.